# How to remove the Nautilus alert of Ubuntu One to synchonize folders?

Tags: ubuntu-one, nautilus

See the link image of Ubuntu One warning highlighted

[image]

But don't remove the sync of "Ubuntu One" folder.

Comment: Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Nautilus, go to menu File -> Ubuntu One -> Hide Ribbon